# LibGDX Fade Out / Fade In Screen Transition

Tags: java, android, libgdx, transition, fade

I'm trying to get a nice fade in/ fade out between two of my screens, and after hours of searching online I have come up empty handed. I've attempted various solutions involving Actions to no avail, and I am not to keen on using TweenEngine, but I would appreciate any help!

Below is the closest solution i've found. This one simply delay the time before the screens switch, yet you don't see a fade in any way.

```
package com.aidanstrong.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.ColorAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer;



public class FadingGame extends Game {
GameScreen gameScreen;
UpgradeScreen upgradeScreen;

private Actor fadeActor = new Actor();
private ShapeRenderer fadeRenderer;


@Override
public void create() {
    gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
    upgradeScreen = new UpgradeScreen(this);
    setScreen(gameScreen);

    fadeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer(8);

}

public void setScreenWithFade (final Screen screen, float duration) {



    fadeActor.clearActions();
    fadeActor.setColor(Color.CLEAR);
    fadeActor.addAction(Actions.sequence(
            Actions.color(Color.BLACK, duration/2f, Interpolation.fade),
            Actions.run(new Runnable(){public void run(){setScreen(screen);}}),
            Actions.color(Color.CLEAR, duration/2f, Interpolation.fade)
    ));
}

@Override
public void render (){
    super.render();

    fadeActor.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    float alpha = fadeActor.getColor().a;
    if (alpha != 0){
        fadeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        fadeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 0, alpha);
        fadeRenderer.rect(-1, -1, 2, 2); //full screen rect w/ identity matrix
        fadeRenderer.end();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you draw the screen to a framebuffer you can do anything you want with it.

Comment: You can checkout Learning Libgdx Game Development 2nd Edition book  Chapter 9!

Answer (score 0):

Add topLayer as an `Image` on your stage and add Action on that Actor. Try this test case:

```
public class GdxTest extends Game {

    FirstScreen firstScreen;
    SecondScreen secondScreen;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        firstScreen=new FirstScreen();
        secondScreen=new SecondScreen();

        setScreen(firstScreen);
    }

    public static Texture getTexture(){

        Pixmap pixmap;
        try {
            pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        }catch (GdxRuntimeException e)
        {
            pixmap=new Pixmap(1,1, Pixmap.Format.RGB565);
        }
        pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pixmap.drawRectangle(0,0,1,1);

        return new Texture(pixmap);
    }
}
```

FirstScreen

```
public class FirstScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    Stage stage;
    Texture texture,white;

    @Override
    public void show() {

        stage=new Stage();

        final Image image = new Image(texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
        image.setSize(200, 200);
        image.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2, stage.getHeight()/2, Align.center);
        stage.addActor(image);

        final Image topLayer = new Image(new TextureRegion(white=GdxTest.getTexture()));
        topLayer.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        topLayer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        stage.addActor(topLayer);

        stage.addListener(new ClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

                topLayer.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.color(Color.BLACK,2),Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        GdxTest gdxTest=((GdxTest)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener());
                        gdxTest.setScreen(gdxTest.secondScreen);
                    }
                })));

                super.clicked(event, x, y);
            }
        });

        topLayer.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(2));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
        white.dispose();
    }
}
```

SecondScreen

```
public class SecondScreen extends ScreenAdapter{

    Stage stage;
    Texture texture,white;

    @Override
    public void show() {

        stage=new Stage();

        final Image image = new Image(texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
        image.setSize(200, 200);
        image.setPosition(stage.getWidth() / 2, stage.getHeight() / 2, Align.center);
        image.setOrigin(Align.center);
        image.rotateBy(90);
        stage.addActor(image);

        final Image topLayer = new Image(new TextureRegion(white=GdxTest.getTexture()));
        topLayer.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        topLayer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        stage.addActor(topLayer);

        topLayer.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(2));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
        white.dispose();
    }
}
```

Or

You can use FBO, at the top of your stage.

**EDIT**

```
public class GdxTest extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;
    FrameBuffer frameBuffer;
    float delta;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        stage=new Stage();
        {
            final Image image = new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
            image.setSize(200, 200);
            image.setPosition(stage.getWidth() / 2, stage.getHeight() / 2, Align.center);
            stage.addActor(image);
        }

        {
            final Image image = new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
            image.setSize(200, 200);
            image.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/3, stage.getHeight()/3, Align.center);
            stage.addActor(image);
        }

        {
            final Image image = new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
            image.setSize(200, 200);
            image.setPosition(stage.getWidth()*.75f, stage.getHeight()*.75f, Align.center);
            stage.addActor(image);
        }

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        delta=1;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        if(delta>0)delta-=.01f;


        frameBuffer.begin();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        frameBuffer.end();

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

        stage.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(stage.getBatch().getProjectionMatrix().idt());

        stage.getBatch().begin();
        stage.getBatch().draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(),-1,1,2,-2);
        stage.getBatch().end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        frameBuffer.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        if(frameBuffer !=null && (frameBuffer.getWidth()!=width || frameBuffer.getHeight()!=height )) {
            frameBuffer.dispose();
            frameBuffer=null;
        }

        if(frameBuffer==null){
            try {
                frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, width, height, false);
            }catch (GdxRuntimeException e){
                frameBuffer=new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565,width,height,false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found your answer hard to apply to my situation as I want to keep on fading back and forth between the screens whenever I switch. Is there anyway you could show me how to use FBO?